# Android Studio 1.4 Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Android App developing.  Today I tried to update my app to android new material design. So I used Android studio (1.4) navigation Drawer Activity. Problem is I cant understand  how to use navigation bar to navigate between my actives. It different from online tutorials I seen. It dosen't use  Fragments. 
I can change names, icons .. etc  the problem is  I cant understand how to navigate between activities using navigation drawer ?

thank you

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem but got fixed.

Follow the steps below:

1.open the "content_main.xml" file located in the "layout" folder.

2.use the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">    

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame">

       </FrameLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

3. go to the "onNavigationItemSelected" method:

> ```
>    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>
>         int id = item.getItemId();
>         Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
>
>         if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
>
>             FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>             ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
>             ft.commit();
>
>         } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
>
>
>         } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
>
>
>         } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
>
>
>         } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
>
>
>         } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
>
>
>         }
>
>         //Close Drawer After Action
>         DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>
>         return true;
> ```

Comment: Actually, he asked Navigation Drawer with activites, but your code is with Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, this is better to use fragments, for each nav item, replace your current fragment in your main activity, it will be simple to do. See fragments section in android dev guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use fragment not activity to add content on each navigation option.(after creating application using Navigation Drawer Activity option in Android Studio).

content_main.xml (assign id to this relative layout, Example:android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.root.netutility.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment">

        <!--<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java (You change fragments like this)

```
   @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;     
        if (id == R.id.ping_tab) {          
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            toolbar.setTitle("First");
        } else if (id == R.id.traceroute_tab) {
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            toolbar.setTitle("Second"); // if you wan to change title
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragment = new FourthFragment();
        }
        if(fragment != null) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relative_layout_for_fragment, fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```